# How do you create a custom font in AndEngine?

Tags: android, fonts, andengine

How in the world do you create a custom front? Almost straight from the example:

```
BitmapTextureAtlas font_texture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR); 
    mFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(font_texture, this, "comic.ttf", 18f, true, Color.WHITE);
```

Yet I get this error:

```
The method createFromAsset(FontManager, ITexture, AssetManager, String, float, boolean, int) in the type FontFactory is not applicable for the arguments (BitmapTextureAtlas, TestGFX5Activity, String, float, boolean, Color)
```

I've tried many different combinations and can't get anything to work. I want the font "comic.ttf", size 18, and white. How do I do this and not get that error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally found the answer:

```
final ITexture fontTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(),256,256);

mFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(this.getFontManager(),fontTexture,this.getAssets(),"COMIC.TTF",18f,true,Color.WHITE);
```

*But* you must import android.graphics.Color *not* org.andengine.util.color.Color!!!